# Javascript: multiple fetches

Tags: javascript, authentication, fetch

I have the following problem. I have a server who implemented his own authentication process. For that they take the credentials as body.

```js
async function authenticate(){
    var cred = JSON.stringify({
        "email": "user@test.de",
        "password": "1234"
      });

    const response = await fetch("http://.../rest/auth/login", {
        method: 'POST',
        mode: 'cors',
        credentials: 'same-origin',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: cred
    })
}
```

The response has the code 200 and says "login successfull!" and has a SET-COOKIE header has
the session cookie.

Now I've a second request with which I load the actual data. But when I try this and I get the response code  401: Unauthorized.

```js
async function getData(){
    const now = new Date()
    const response = await fetch(`http://.../rest/....`)
    console.log(response)
    const data = await JSON.parse(response)
    console.log(data)
}
authenticate()
.then((res) => {
    console.log(res)
    getData().then(reso => console.log(reso))
})
```

Im not sure how to handle this problem.

I've already checked all responses and everything worked except that the second request doesnt use the Cookie in their request. I've also tried to use the `WithCredentials=true` option but without success.

**EDIT**

I changed the credentials from

```
credentials: 'cross-origin' -> credentials: 'include'
```

Since im calling an extern Server from localhost.
But i get still an 401 Error.

Comment: You forgot the `credentials` option in the second requet.

Comment: "I've also tried to use the WithCredentials=true option" — How did you try using that?

Comment: @Quentin OP said that 2nd request is supposed to be using session(?) cookie. You shouldn't need to resend the credentials

Comment: @ControlAltDel — Cookies **are** credentials!

Comment: I hope this is just for practice. You shouldn't be sending authentication credentials unencrypted over http in the real world

Comment: Hang one. You said `credentials: 'same-origin',` but are using an *absolute* URL. Is this a same origin request or a cross origin request?

Comment: @Quentin Cookies are absolutely NOT credentials. They are tokens that link to an established user session.

Comment: @ControlAltDel — For the purposes of the `credentials` option for `fetch`, they **are** credentials. (And a if a token with a unique ID that tells the server who you are so it can associate your request with a bucket of your private data isn't a credential, then someone has changed the English language on me while I wasn't looking).

Comment: @Quentin I don't want to argue with you over the semantics over these words on a 3rd party's question, but there are significant differences between user name & password vs. a cookie. For one, cookies expire. IMO it's wrong to conflate login credentials with cookies

Comment: @ControlAltDel Take your complaint to the Fetch API designers. They used the `credentials:` option to control both HTTP authentication and cookies.

Comment: @ControlAltDel — Nothing about the definition of credentials requires that they don't expire. My Windows password expires every 3 months. My 2FA credentials tend to expire every 30 seconds. Your option doesn't really matter though. The `credentials` option affects cookies. That's a fact.

Comment: @Quentin So observed. When I'm wrong, I'm wrong :)